# How do I compile and run GCC 4.9.x?

Tags: gcc, gcc4.9

I'm running debian wheezy and wanted to upgrade from GCC 4.7.2 to GCC 4.9.0.

As per [these instructions](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC) I installed `libgmp-dev`, `libmpfr-dev` and `libmpc-dev` (my package manager gave me versions 2:5.0.5+dfsg-2, 3.1.0-5 and 0.9-4 respectively) and ran the following to compile gcc (note that in my case it was 4.9.0 instead of 4.6.2):

```
tar xzf gcc-4.6.2.tar.gz
cd gcc-4.6.2
./contrib/download_prerequisites
cd ..
mkdir objdir
cd objdir
$PWD/../gcc-4.6.2/configure --prefix=$HOME/gcc-4.6.2 
make
make install
```

I now have a `objdir` directory full of stuff, but where is g++, and where should I put this directory?

I'm guessing I should move it to `usr/local` and add something to my `PATH` variable, but I don't know what exactly, and how to make sure it is searched before my old gcc install.

Comment: No `gcc-4.9.0` directory with the binaries showed up in your home directory?

Comment: a lot of things are very interesting: 1) Why you install a 4.9.0 in a 4.6.2 directory? :-) 2. Why you use $PWD/../xyz instead of ../xyz ? You will find the executables in $HOME/gcc<nice-version>/bin/

Comment: @Klaus all those things are already explained. I installed it to 4.9.0 and I don't really know why they used `$PWD` but it works fine. Can I somehow make sure that when I type `g++` it points to my new install instead of the gcc that came with debian?

Comment: Depending on your shell (bash?) you can edit the ~/.bashrc file. Add a new line at the end: `export PATH=/<your home>/gcc-<your gcc version>/bin:$PATH`. Now you start a new shell and type `gcc --version`. This should be the new one.

Comment: N.B. you only need to *either* install the `libgmp-dev`, `libmpfr-dev` and `libmpc-dev` packages *or* run the `contrib/download_prerequisites` script. I thought the GCC wiki page made that clear: _"**Alternatively**, after extracting the GCC source archive, simply run the `./contrib/download_prerequisites` script in the GCC source directory."_

Comment: Also, when using the new `g++` make sure you read and understand http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.how_to_set_paths

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After doing these commands (note the `--prefix` option of configure)

```
$PWD/../gcc-4.9.0/configure --prefix=$HOME/gcc-4.9.0 
make install
```

the new gcc will be installed in `$HOME/gcc-4.9.0` directory (there should be subdirectories  like `bin`, `lib`, `share` inside it).

Full path to `gcc` will be `$HOME/gcc-4.9.0/bin/gcc`, and `g++` (which is symlink to `gcc`) will be here: `$HOME/gcc-4.9.0/bin/g++`.

There can be no separate `g++` in objdir because `gcc` compiler driver implements drivers for several languages; the mode (C or C++) is selected based on `argv[0]` (name of binary, which was used to run driver: `gcc` or `g++`; this mode also affects linking flags) and on source file extensions (`gcc` accepts both C and C++ programs as input for compilation into object files). So, `g++` may be generated as symlink by `make install`, and the place to store generated symlink is `$prefix/bin`.

After building the GCC and installing it in the `$HOME/gcc-4.9.0` directory, you can use it; but default system gcc will be not updated. Update of distributive gcc should be done via distributive tools (`apt`, `dpkg-build`, etc). Current prebuild version of system-wide gcc for Wheezy is [4.7.2](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/gcc),  [4.8.2](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/gcc) for Jessie and Sid and [4.9-2](https://packages.debian.org/experimental/gcc) for "Experimental".

Comment: So I can't replace the `g++` command to somehow point to this new binary? Will I have to manually point to that directory every time I want to run g++?

Comment: you can change your own $PATH environment variable, adding new directory to it to the left of `/usr/bin`. For example, is you use bash, add to the `~/.bashrc` file: `export PATH=~/gcc-4.9.0/bin:$PATH`. Then open new terminal to check.

Comment: @osgx: Thanks for the detailed information about installing and using gcc-4.9.0. I am able to install and use the latest gcc/g++ on my GNU/Linux terminal the way the steps has been mentioned in this SO post. However I would like to know whether I can safely delete $HOME/objdir directory? It has around 3.3GB size on my machine.

Comment: Mantosh Kumar, Yes, after installing (`make install`) you can delete the directory where the project was built, there is no dependence on it. The only useful information here is "`config.log`" file (it has copy of all  `configure` options and list of actually enabled features) and list of directories (`ls -l`, because it is possible to merge gcc, gdb, binutils into single srcdir/objdir and use one `configure` to get them all). Personally I always save `config.log` and file list from all build dirs (objdirs), they helps remaking the project (e.g. when next minor version of gcc is available).