# Errors in installing Homebrew and git

Tags: linux, git, anaconda, homebrew, libgcc

I am trying to work on a linux based external server. I need to install Homebrew and anaconda. So, I have installed anaconda as usual in my home directory. But when I tried to install homebrew, I get the following errors:

```
fatal: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-9d2d97f367d3ebfa65a3b708b2d87333a8eb2bf0.pack cannot be mapped: Cannot allocate memory

error: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core did not send all necessary objects

Failed during: git fetch --force origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Ok, then I tried to install `git` using `conda`. However, I have encountered another error, which is:

```
libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work
```

I tried to install the GCC library using this link [How do I compile and run GCC 4.9.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23312047/how-do-i-compile-and-run-gcc-4-9-x)

But then again, I encountered the problem of "cannot allocate memory". As I am working on an external cluster with many CPUs, I assume I have enough memory and space because I am working with many genomes.

Also, I cannot used `sudo` as I am not authorised to do that. I also tried to get the `apt-get` command but it shows that `apt-get command not found`.
Can anybody please help me to solve these problems?
Thank you.

Comment: "cannot allocate memory" means that you *don't* have enough memory. What we don't know is how much "enough" would be: are these things trying to allocate 500 kilobytes, 500 megabytes, or 500 gigabytes? Find out how much they want, and see if you can get your VM expanded as necessary.

Comment: Ok, I will check that.